# How to post the values controller to model in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

the code is as follows, in view file am having the form action as `complete_survey()`, and am also mentioning the controller and model as follows, will the values be posted into model in order to insert into the database or not. can someone help me please thanks, or i have to use as `$this->survey_model->auto_save_projected($_POST);`

controller

```
public function complete_survey()
    {
        $this->survey_model->submit_survey($this->session, $_POST);
        $this->survey_model->auto_save_projected();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message_success', 'Thanks for taking the survey!');
        redirect('survey/home','message_success');  
    }
```

model

```
function auto_save_projected(){
      $projected = array(
            'survey_id' => $surveyId,
            'provisional_compare' => $post['higher'],
            'percentage' => $post['range'],
            'alternate_funding_mechanisms' => $post['high'],
            'alternate_funding_expl' => $post['state_note'],
            'projected_budget_created_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'projected_budget_modified_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        );
}
```

Comment: in model no actions..?  $surveyId ?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `$this->survey_model->auto_save_projected();` in controller all your view page values will be available in model also. You don't need to use `$this->survey_model->auto_save_projected($_POST);`.
In model you can access the values as:

```
function auto_save_projected(){
  $projected = array(
        'survey_id' => $surveyId,
        'provisional_compare' => $this->input->post('higher'),
        'percentage' => $this->input->post('range'),
        'alternate_funding_mechanisms' => $this->input->post('high'),
        'alternate_funding_expl' => $this->input->post('state_note'),
        'projected_budget_created_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'projected_budget_modified_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    );
}
```

But in your model `$surveyId` is coming from where?You have not passed this value from your controller also. Check for this.

Comment: am having $this->session->store['survey_id'] value into $surveyId, i forgot to add that am sorry

Comment: you are using codeigniter's seesion so this is not the way to store session values. Refer http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html on how to store session values

Comment: hi i have a doubt can someone help me please